# Find out which segment the image resides in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a rotating wheel of 5 images. What I would like to find out is which image ends up in the top right corner.

Is there any way I can realize which one is in the top right corner through coding?

Thanks :)

Comment: You have a WHEEL with a top right 'corner'??

Comment: LOL. its actually a square but the image is an actual wheel. Thus to me its the wheel's corner

Answer (score 0):

If your images are going to end up in specific spots, meaning you know exactly what will be the position of an image when it is in the 'top right corner', you can check the origin (of directly the frame) of that image view.

```
BOOL bingo = CGRectEqualToRect(imageViewRect, topRightCornerRect);
```

or

```
BOOL bingo = CGPointEqualToPoint(imageViewOrigin, topRightCornerRectOrigin);
```